# Use Pig UDF function outside FOREACH

Tags: java, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to use UDF outside of FOREACH.
I have to do a function that will calculate the filenames to load from Pig, and I'd like to do that with Java code.
The function must return to me :

```
[2018120310, 2018120309, 2018120308, 2018120307, 2018120306, 2018120305, 2018120304, 2018120303, ... ]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about (no examples, code etc.) and I'm pretty sure it's not because I don't know Pig that well.

Comment: i juste want to use User-defined-function outside pig FOREACH. https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html

Comment: Yes it is possible, go for it.